# How to refer to the parent scope in Ember View

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, scope

I'm new to Ember, here is a simple code to let arrow button to increase and decrease the value of `amount` property:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
    afterRenderEvent: function() {
        $('.spinner .increase').on('click', function() {
            this.incrementProperty('amount');
        });
        $('.spinner .decrese').on('click', function() {
            this.decrementProperty('amount');
        });

    },
    template: ProductView
});
```

The problem is the `this` not refer to the Ember.View Object, but the scope of the function, How to solve this problem?

Plus I think use jQuery to manipulate the element is not the ember way. Should I create view for each arrow button?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maintaining a reference to the original context and then using it in the closures should solve your problem:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
    afterRenderEvent: function() {
        var self = this;
        $('.spinner .increase').on('click', function() {
            self.incrementProperty('amount');
        });
        $('.spinner .decrese').on('click', function() {
            self.decrementProperty('amount');
        });
    },
    template: ProductView
});
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. Your solution works! Do you think it's the right practice to do this? or set a on event for the view itself?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ember, sorry :/ If it was pure jquery I'd definitely do it liks this, also maintaining a reference to the original context is common practice.

Comment: Correct Answer, incorrect way to do this in Ember (and fails to clean up the event handler, not your fault, but the Ember way would), if you'll update it to use actions I'll gladly reverse my down vote.

Comment: If you have a better answer then just post it yourself and I'll upvote it. Mine isn't incorrect as you said so no need to downvote ...